# Process.Start opens process but not application on Windows Server 2019

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I am building a dashboard for one of our departments that is going to monitor the status of several VBA scripts/macros. One of the features I want is to be able to start the script/macro remotely via my Blazor application. I have so far managed to start the process on the server with the following line.

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe","", uname, Password, domain);
```

I can see the process started in the task manager but the application itself never starts (cannot physically see the application).

One of the requirements is that the user (service account) will always be logged on to the server (could this be the issue that the service account is logged in?). The Blazor application is running with the same identity in the application pool as the service account that is logged in

Comment: If you know what is session isolation, you know that's perfectly normal, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: That opened up a whole new world. Ended up finding below article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Which then led me to the following article that I am reading through and trying to understand (it is on a high level :) )